# Смена картинки при развертывании Меню

Tags: jquery, меню, javascript

**Есть скрипт для развертывания меню,**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sliEsq').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().children('.sliesQ').toggle('fast');
        return false;
    });
});
```

**как его допилить чтобы при развертывании менялась картинка:
К примеру картинка(+) на картинку(-)**
Пробовал вставить такой скрипт к картинке:

```
var x=false
function imgchange(obj,imgX,imgY) {
    if  (x){
        obj.src=imgX
    } else {
        obj.src=imgY
    }
    x=!x
}
```

Но меню все равно работает не так как надо

Comment: код покажи в jsfiddle вместе со стилями и html

Comment: shtorm.by сайт меню которое слева

не умею я пользоваться  jsfiddle

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/98bb2b909a13/category.tpl
Вот темплейт меню

Answer (score 1):

Вставляйте картинку фоном.

У элемента `$(this).parent().children('.sliesQ')` в классе добавьте фоновое изображение:

```
background-image: url(../minus.png);
```

Также добавьте еще один класс:

```
.active {
    background-image: url(../plus.png);
}
```

И в `onlick`:

```
$('.sliEsq').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.sliesQ').toggle('fast').toggleClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[click](http://jsfiddle.net/9Sf6K/) вот что тебе нужно, дальше сам допилишь

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично работает теперь.

Comment: Теперь возникла следующая проблема, когда переходишь по ссылке меню, она становиться АКТИВНАЯ, и подкатегории открываются в левом меню. Но картинка остается +(плюс), соответственно когда на нее нажимаешь, подкатегории скрываются, но картинка меняется на -(минус).

Comment: Суть допила такова
Если сслыка активна (.box-category > ul > li ul > li > a.active)
то .sliEsq имеет класс .open

Что бы меню имела вид
+ Категория
+ Категория
- Категория(активная)
   подкатегория
   подкатегория
   подкатегория
+ Категория
+ Категория